# Capacitance of partially filled coaxial cylinders

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

[image: Concentric partially filled cylinders]

Consider a concentric system of (say metallic) cylinders as I have drawn in the picture. A solid/filled cylinder is embedded in the outer one. The red lines are the electrical contacts on the top and bottom "circular plates". The dielectric constant of the medium filling the gap between the two cylinders is $\epsilon_r$.

Is there an analytical solution available/possible for the capacitance for this configuration, if so how? I need to find the dependence on the capacitance on $\Delta$.